# CloudBlockBlob and APIM URI

Tags: c#, azure, azure-api-management, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a function that uses CloudBlockBlob to upload data to a Data Lake.  This is working fine when using the direct URI that contains the query parameters used for authentication e.g. sig
However, I would like to use APIM, in case I have other uses for the DataLake, but I cannot get it to work.  Is this possible?
This is the current exception raised:
`System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: FunctionName. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Access Denied.`

Comment: Are you trying to use APIM as a proxy for Data Lake here?

Comment: yes, I want all my datalake calls going through APIM